# How to rewrite Apache Iceberg data files to another format?

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-lake, apache-iceberg

I'd like to use the Apache Iceberg Apache Spark-Java based API for rewriting data files on my Iceberg table. I'm writing my data files in an Avro format, but I'd like to rewrite them to Parquet. Is it possible in a somewhat easy way?

I've researched the API of https://iceberg.apache.org/javadoc/1.0.0/org/apache/iceberg/actions/RewriteDataFiles.html, with the builder of:

```java
SparkActions
    .get()
    .rewriteDataFiles(table)
    .filter(Expressions.equal("date", "2020-08-18"))
    .option("target-file-size-bytes", Long.toString(500 * 1024 * 1024)) // 500 MB
    .execute();
```

But I could not find how can I change the files format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset your table property

   ```
   ALTER TABLE prod.db.sample SET TBLPROPERTIES (
       'write.format.default'='parquet'
   )
   ```
2. rewrite your data
   spark SQL

   ```
   CALL catalog_name.system.rewrite_data_files(table => 'db.sample', strategy => 'sort',sort_order => 'id',options => map('rewrite-all','true'))
   ```

or use the spark-java API, as you listed above.

Comment: If I reset my table properties I'd still be able to write Avro files to the table?